# Class-validator ignores ValidateNested objects

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I am having problems with nested objects validation. This is my code, and it totally ignores validating nested objects, I can't figure it out why:

```
import { IsNumber, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import "reflect-metadata";

export class SubClass {

    @IsNumber()
    public x : number;

    @IsNumber()
    public y : number;

    constructor( x : number, y : number){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y; 
    };
};

export class Class {

    @IsArray()
    @ValidateNested({always: true, each: true})
    @Type(()=> SubClass)
    public nested ?: SubClass[];

    constructor(data : SubClass[]) {
        this.nested = data;
    }
}
```

Everything passes, empty objects, wrong types, etc.. Plase help me to figure it out somehow..

Example : 
Test with : 
{
x : 'asd123',
y: 'aasdf123' 
} passes.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else having this kind of problem, I've figured out the solution. As the documentation says, the validated property must be a Class instance so the validation decorator will work. So, the solution for this case would be:

```
import { IsNumber, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import "reflect-metadata";

export class SubClass {

    @IsNumber()
    public x : number;

    @IsNumber()
    public y : number;

    constructor( x : number, y : number){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y; 
    }
}

export class Class {

    @IsArray()
    @ValidateNested({always: true, each: true})
    @Type(()=> SubClass)
    public nested ?: SubClass[];

    constructor(data : SubClass[]) {
        this.nested = data.map((data : SubClass) => new SubClass(data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When property is missing in the req and you want set a default value

e.g:  filters = new FiltersDm(); in the code below

documentation says: "Please note that nested object must be an instance of a class, otherwise @ValidateNested won't know what class is target of validation..."
https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator

you need to instantiate your nested class (it must be a class)
filters = new FiltersDm();

I'm using nest 9 with class-validator

```
 export class FiltersDm {
 @ApiProperty()
 @IsArray()
 @IsEnum(ModulesEnum, { each: true })
 incidentTypes: ModulesEnum[] = [];

 @ApiProperty()
 @IsArray()
 tags: string[] = [];

 @ApiProperty()
 @IsArray()
 @IsEnum(AssetsDm, { each: true })
 assets: AssetsDm[] = [];
}

 export class NotificationsRequestDto {
 @ApiProperty()
 @IsEmail()
 email: string;

 @ApiProperty()
 @Type(() => FiltersDm)
 @ValidateNested({ each: true })
 @IsDefined()
 @IsNotEmptyObject()
 @IsObject()
 filters = new FiltersDm();
 }
```